# Retrieve Amazon ECS Fargate Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I created a cloudformation template that will start ECS with fargate but i would like to know is there anyway to catch Fargate's public ip as output in cloudformation or maybe even do it via aws cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for that. The resource would be a **lambda function** that would use AWS SDK to query your Fargate cluster/service/task and return its IP address back to the CloudFormation stack for further use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there anyway to retrieve ENI ID of my fargate after that i created it with cloudformation? i mean can it get it as output because as i know it can possible to get public ip with eni id.

Comment: @Fardin You can do what ever you want using a custom resource. You are developing it, so it is only up to you want it can do and return.

Comment: Thanks, I already get that IP with AWS CLi

Comment: @Fardin No problem. If you know how to do it using AWS CLI, then you can replicate this using AWS SDK such as boto3 in a custom resource. Also, if the answer helped, its [acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) would be appreciated.